# Calculated field not updating with Kendo-UI grid and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I have a kendo-ui grid with order lines.  There is a `Qty`, `Price` and `Total` column.  The Total column is calculated `( Qty x Price )`.

For editing, I use a custom popup Window which displays some additional information and lets the user change the `Qty` and `Price`.  When they do this, I want the `Total` to update automatically in the custom edit form.

Here is the grid's column definition for the total column:

```
{
   field: "total",
   title: "Total",
   width: 60,
   template: "#=qty*price#"
}
```

Here is the input field in the edit form:

```
<input name="total" style="width: 60px" />
```

**Here is the problem:**  when I change the quantity or price in the edit form, the total gets updated only in the grid (which is underneath the pop-up edit form), but the total field in the edit form does not (it is empty).

As a test, I put both `#=total#` and `#=qty*price#` in the edit form;

- the former is null
- the latter is the static number that was the result of the
  calculation when the form was rendered

it does not get updated.

Here is a Plunker that shows the issue:
http://plnkr.co/edit/cZw18btauqb9RPEpd5Kc?p=preview

**How to make the total field in the edit form calculated?**
(preferably using the Kendo-ui template mechanism or AngularJS, but a jQuery hack would do as a last resort)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Templates don't provide two-way data-binding, so they won't automatically update after they're first generated.

You probably want to use a calculated field for your model in the data source schema:

```
schema: {
    model: {
        id: "itemNo",
        fields: {
            id: {
                type: "string",
                editable: false
            },
            price: {
                type: "number"
            },
            qty: {
                type: "number"
            }
        },
        total: function () {
            return this.get("qty") * this.get("price");
        }
    }
},
```

([demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/bRaFZFjrzR3IyeVrmulR?p=preview))

Answer (score 2):

Further if you are using "incell" editing you can use the "change" event of the grid dataSource to track changes in connected fields and force the calculated field to update. Such exmaple could be:

[Grid: Incell editing with calculated column auto refresh](http://dojo.telerik.com/ufECe)